# Jquery is not loading properly in Internet explorer 11 browser until page refresh

Tags: jquery

Im using this jquery plugin called  Slidorion with SPServices.

On firefix,Chrome when the page loads first it works all good.
But in IE 11 it doesnt work on first load until i refresh it.

I have also used this below but no luck.Also use document ready no LUCK.
Added it to my masterpage at the end before the body tag NO LUCK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      //your code here
      $('#slidorion').slidorion({
            speed: 1000,
            interval: 4000,
            effect: 'slideLeft'
       });

    });
     </script>
```

Any ideas and thanks in Advance

### Just added

I have tried this also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");

   function myCustomFunctionName() {
     $('#slidorion').slidorion({
        speed: 1000,
        interval: 4000,
        effect: 'slideLeft'
   });
   //alert("sdfds");
}


</script>
```

If i run the debugger f12 or firebug and load the page it works.
This is only ON IE 11 and its driving me crazy.
It only works when i refresh the page or even when i have an alert on the page

Comment: did you try document.ready() ?

Comment: Yes Taran.I did

Comment: How and where do you reference jQuery?

Comment: @naijacoder Try adding a 50ms or more timer between the `$(window).load(function(){` and `$('#slidorion').slidorion({`. Don't have a reference right now, but basically on SharePoint even the document.ready() isn't always enough to make sure the scripts have been loaded on the page

Comment: Try running this after everything finishes loading using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");`

Comment: Hi uberz91 how can i wrap my window.load into _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push? 
Cheers

Comment: @naijacoder Instead of using window.load, wrap your logic into a function and call _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Moe i did try your solution too but no LUCK :) IE 11 just doesnt do it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @naijacoder that answers my "Where", thank you, now on to "How" :)

Comment: Have you checked dev tools console? Are there other instances of jQuery on the page (conflict, very common, when the plugin is loaded `$.fn.plugin` is undefined, but this is easily seen in console)? Is anything else conflicting with `window.$`? How do you reference jQuery, the plugin and your script?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: John-M its SharePoint 2013

Comment: Thanks eirikb will give that a try but remember as i mentioned Chrome and Firefox is fine.

Comment: Hi Guys the console.log error here: http://i58.tinypic.com/514qo4.png and Masterpage here : http://i57.tinypic.com/2d167vn.png . It seems to me its just an IE issue

Comment: tinypic.com may be blocked by firewall, can you please add the error lines as a comment or into the question

Comment: @naijacoder have you tried using _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push? The multiple links that I read suggest using this instead of window.load.

Comment: I have posted what i added in my original post.No idea why this wont work in IE

Comment: What version of the SharePoint are you running?
If it is version 2013, there are lots of issues running in IE11, try to run in compatibility view when using IE. In your master page header:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />

Answer (score 1):

You must await jQuery too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");

   function myCustomFunctionName() {
      jQuery(function(){
          $('#slidorion').slidorion({
              speed: 1000,
              interval: 4000,
              effect: 'slideLeft'
           });
           //alert("sdfds");
      });
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert still no show. I gave up with IE 11 :(